# Powershell command-line throw

Tags: powershell

For testing purposes, I want to create a "fake" process that always crashes.

Since I'm using Powershell to do that, I was thinking of running another PS instance with a command that just throws an exception (`throw 'test'`).

After banging my head for a few minutes over a so simple task, I have found that:

```
powershell -command "& throw 'test'"
```

yields an error "throw is not understood", but:

```
powershell -command "& { throw 'test' }"
```

throws the exception I want.

What is the difference? Why do I need curly braces around the throw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first version you're attempting to call a *program* called throw, thus it fails.

It would actually work fine if you simply did:

```
powershell -command "throw 'test'"
```

In the second version, you use the curly braces, so the expression is evaluated by `&` as a script block rather than trying to invoke a program